# Access the Values in this Array [API Result]

Tags: jquery, html, json, api

I've been trying to learn API's, I have a couple working but this one is stumping me and I can't get it to work/display.

I'm trying to access a specific property in the response, which appears multiple times, and then display it on the page.

So far I have the call working, I just need this part completing:

```
          success: function (resp) {


          });
```

Then I am going to try and list all of these results in a table:

```
    {
  "gameId": 2540635808,
  "mapId": 11,
  "gameMode": "CLASSIC",
  "gameType": "MATCHED_GAME",
  "gameQueueConfigId": 2,
  "participants": [
    {
      "teamId": 100,
      "spell1Id": 11,
      "spell2Id": 4,
      "championId": 19,
      "profileIconId": 23,
      "summonerName": "Like or Leave",
      "bot": false,
      "summonerId": 54108020,
      "runes": [
        {
          "count": 7,
          "runeId": 5245
        },
        {
          "count": 1,
          "runeId": 5290
        },
        {
          "count": 4,
          "runeId": 5316
        },
        {
          "count": 2,
          "runeId": 5337
        }
      ],
      "masteries": [
        {
          "rank": 4,
          "masteryId": 6111
        },
        {
          "rank": 5,
          "masteryId": 6211
        },
        {
          "rank": 1,
          "masteryId": 6223
        },
        {
          "rank": 5,
          "masteryId": 6232
        },
        {
          "rank": 1,
          "masteryId": 6242
        },
        {
          "rank": 5,
          "masteryId": 6252
        },
        {
          "rank": 1,
          "masteryId": 6262
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "teamId": 100,
      "spell1Id": 4,
      "spell2Id": 3,
      "championId": 25,
      "profileIconId": 774,
      "summonerName": "SackOfRyze",
      "bot": false,
      "summonerId": 71487363,
      "runes": [
        {
          "count": 6,
          "runeId": 5245
        },
```

If someone could help me get the "summonerName" to be displayed, THAT WOULD BE SO HELPFUL.

I'm not sure if it matters, but the top part of the array, with "GameID, MapID" etc has no match from the actual call. The match the call finds is one of the summonerID contained in the response. Like I said, not sure if it matters but I thought I'd mention.

I thought I would access it using something like this:

```
players = resp[summmonerID].participants.length;
document.getElementById("listPlayers").innerHTML = players;

              resp[summonerID].participants.forEach(function (item) {
  document.getElementById("masteryPagesAll").innerHTML = document.getElementById("playersAll").innerHTML + item.summonerName + "<br />";
              });
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more concise/readable output

Comment: Hi, sorry I thought there would be enough what more would you like me to show you?

Comment: The one with more readable output. I meant the data inside `resp` on success calllback.

Answer (score 0):

First of all that response is string. You should convert it to an object to access its attributes and values.

```
var data = JSON.parse(resp);
```

Then you can use that data object like you thought.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I'm still learning so correct me if I'm wrong but I thought including this:                 type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {

                },       means I don't need to parse the response?

Comment: Yes, `dataType:'json'` should work. For verifying that you can `console.log(typeof(resp));`. Your code looks fine, do you get any console errors when you run it?

Comment: Only this: error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error getting Summoner data2!"); so it is definately hitting the second API call. Also, I've been testing in Google Chrome and the API Call returns code "200" with the URL matching what it should be (successful call is made) but I cannot seem to display all of the players names :(

Comment: Hey, its just showing me the text "error getting Summoner data2!" :/

Comment: That's string you have alerted, try `alert('errorThrown')` or `console.log(errorThrown)` to see value of it.

Comment: alert('errorThrown') just shows "errorThrown" console.log does nothing (I presume thats used if its a CMD app)?? thanks again

Comment: `console.log` is for debugging the app, it doesn't matter where you run. Can you upload complete json response?

Comment: My apologies, I think I've read a little to much this morning. The console error shows: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :         if I click it it takes me to the start of the response. Any ideas? :)

Comment: That means response is not a valid json. Remove `dataType:'json',` and check response content by `console.log(resp)` or `document.body.innerHTML = resp;`. Also you can inspect network requests and responses using chrome's inpsector.